# Inconsistent tf.print results

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I was trying to understand the executing order in tensorflow graph. When I was running the following code. `tf.print` prints undetermined results.

```py
import tensorflow as tf

for _ in range(20):
    tf.reset_default_graph()
    use_resource = False
    v = tf.Variable(0, trainable=False, use_resource=use_resource, name='v')
    v_op1 = v.assign_add(1, name='v_op1')
    v_op2 = v.assign_add(2, name='v_op2')

    with tf.control_dependencies([v_op1]):
        w1 = tf.print('msg1:', v, name='v--w')
    with tf.control_dependencies([w1, v_op2]):
        w2 = tf.print('msg2:', v, '\n', name='w--w')
    with tf.Session() as sess:
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        sess.run(w2)
```

Here are the output of 20 repetitions. Sometimes, it prints "msg1: 3", sometimes it prints "msg1: 1". So what's going on here?

```py
msg1: 3
msg2: 3 

msg1: 3
msg2: 3 

msg1: 3
msg2: 3 

msg1: 3
msg2: 3 

msg1: 3
msg2: 3 

msg1: 3
msg2: 3 

msg1: 3
msg2: 3 

msg1: 3
msg2: 3 

msg1: 3
msg2: 3 

msg1: 3
msg2: 3 

msg1: 1
msg2: 3 

msg1: 3
msg2: 3 

msg1: 3
msg2: 3 

msg1: 3
msg2: 3 

msg1: 3
msg2: 3 

msg1: 3
msg2: 3 

msg1: 3
msg2: 3 

msg1: 3
msg2: 3 

msg1: 3
msg2: 3 

msg1: 1
msg2: 3
```

Comment: What version of TF are you using? Personally, I cannot reproduce on TF 1.12.0 (CPU or GPU), but it might depend on the particular machine setup. These things are always a bit mystifying, you may see if using [`read_value`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable#read_value) helps, since it is supposed to ensure the variable is read with the control dependencies. I think what happens is that sometimes an old, cached variable value is picked up with the operation under control dependencies, but honestly I'm not sure if that is expected behaviour or not...

Comment: @jdehesa I'm using tf-1.14-gpu. My guess is same as yours. The w1 would read the v value before or after v_op2 is done...But I'm not sure what's exactly happening behind it...

Answer (score 0):

I think what's happening is you're creating a race between w1 and v_op2, and they're both being executed simultaneously. (with theses lines)

```py
with tf.control_dependencies([w1, v_op2]):
```

for example if v_op2 is executed before w1 then 2 is added to `v` then when w1 is executed it adds 1 to it making msg_1 print 3. However when w1 is able to be completed before v_op2 is executed then 2 is added to `v` after.

e.g. case 1

```
v_op2 executed:
v = 2
w1 executed:
v = 3
print(v)
```

case 2

```
w1 executed
v = 1
print(v)
v_op2 executed
v=3
```

Comment: That seems the only possible reason for now.

Comment: if you were making actual code though I'd try not to have separate dependencies that use the same variable